# "npx create-react-app" results in '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Error code 9009

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

node version v14.15.4.
npm version npm@7.5.2
Path variables I have added or added by installation:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\

C:\users\msi\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
```

Command:

`$ npx create-react-app todolist`

Full Error:

```
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code 9009

npm ERR! path C:\Users\MSI\react

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app todolist

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app todolist

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-07T18_47_37_406Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does the output of the command "node --version" contain nodejs version ?

Comment: Yes. Its showing v14.15.4

Comment: Try, uninstalling the create-react-app using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` command and then reinstalling it globally using `npm install -g create-react-app` command.

Comment: @ThilinaLakshan You aren't supposed to use CRA globally. `npm install create-react-app && npx create-react-app` is the way it was intended.